# React: вопрос по архитектуре работы с props и локальными состояниями

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Есть компонент `LoginForm`, который на вход получает среди свойств и `props.notification`, содержащий информацию о нотификациях(предупреждениях, ошибках) и т.д., которая отображается пользователю.

Если пользователь в форме начинает вводить какой-то текст, то полученные нотификации больше не отображаются. Но если нотификации были изменены, то начинают отображаться снова.

Реализовал это следующим способом (оставил только относящийся к этому функционалу код, чтобы не захламлять экран)

```
const LoginForm = (props) => {
    // контроль состояний
    const [notification, setNotification] = useState(undefined);

    // эффект: отслеживание изменения нотификаций от родителя
    useEffect(() => {
        setNotification(props.notification);
    }, [props.notification])
   
    // событие: изменение полей
    const onFieldsChange = () => {
        // сбросить нотификации
        setNotification(undefined);
    }

    // отрисовать компонент
    return (...);
};
```

такие вопросы:

1. можно ли обойтись без `useEffect`
2. не дичь ли я закодил для реализации этого функционала (можно было бы проще, но тогда этот компонент должен был бы общаться с данными напрямую, хотя ими заведует его родитель - некоторый конечный автомат, а LoginForm обычная форма, которая ни о чем не знает)
3. насколько вообще мой подход уместен, а именно:

- компонент формы (всякие поля, заполняемые пользователем и т.п.)
  должен знать только о данных, которые вводят ему, как их
  обрабатывать, корректировать и т.д.
- то, что с данными творится дальше компонент знать не должен (а значит
  и не должен иметь доступ к этим данным или другим служебным
  механизмам)
- компонент не должен знать откуда он получает props (понятно, что от родителя, но как они попали к родителю - сгенерировал ли он их сам или получил откуда-то) и модифицировать эти данные для своих локальных нужд тоже не должен (только копию данных)

Comment: Вполне себе хороший компонент. Я бы в функции onFieldsChange добавил проверку, что бы не сетить при каждом изменении полей, если нотификаций нет(это вызывает рендер). Тип данных изменил бы с undefined на тип самих нотификаций и возможно стоит родителю сообщать, что нотификации удалены(если надо, чтобы почистил). Без эффекта можно попробовать обойтись, если родитель перерисовывается и всегда в дочернем рендерить сами props.notify, но могут быть нюансы

Comment: Swad, да, я тоже думал о том, что можно сообщать родителю об удалении нотификации, тогда и эффекта не нужно - все будет замечательно работать, но тут как раз подумал, что это будет отхождение от идеи, что работать надо только с тем, что получил, а при передаче сообщения родителю компонент как бы получается обладает знанием, что родитель что-то должен с нотификацией делать и даже заставляет его это делать, что вроде как не очень хорошо. На счет изменения onFieldsChange типа делать проверку `if notification: setNotification(undefined)`? По поводу использования не undefined-чем такой плох подход?

Comment: @SwaD, а разве попытка сменить `undefined` на `undefined` вызовет перерендер?

Comment: Компонент работает с тем что есть. Компонент сказал родителю - я все принял, родитель обнулил пропс и передал в компонент. Компонент отрисовал что есть. Тут все норм и тоже правильно, т.к. родитель передаст пустоту. Если у вас **props.notification** строка, то дефолтное значение должна быть срока **''**. Что бы компонент понимал всегда, что имеет дело со строкой.

Comment: @OliverPatterson Можно конечно потестировать на разных версиях реакта, однако сам факт передачи новых(хоть и не измененных данных) данных в стейт, это уже нагрузка. Я бы не стал дергать сеттер без необходимости.